# Converting ModelMetrics REST framework on top of Salesforce SDK iOS

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, ipad

We have an app which was developed by Salesforce previously and they have used ModelMetrics REST framework on top of Salesforce SDK iOS. Now, the development is taken care by our company and I am trying to update the latest Salesforce SDK iOS. I am in the process of changing existing ModelMetrics framework. Is there any forum I could use as I am facing difficulties in doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: Model Metrics was acquired by Salesforce several years ago. Their site [no longer exists](http://modelmetrics.com) and any SDKs they had on Github [have been deleted](https://github.com/ModelMetrics). You're probably barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: So, there is no way I could update the RESTlibrary framework and using it along with the latest SalesforceSDK ios? What do you reckon? Should I have to rewrite whole functionalities which this library did in order to update it with new SalesforceSDK for ios?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about what your framework does. If you have a static library or dynamic framework, then it is closed-source and no, you cannot change it. If you have a bunch of loose .h/.m files, then you have the full source and can make any changes you like. If I were in your place, I would try not to use any code from a company that ceased existing years ago. :)

Comment: It has got a framework called SA_Base.framework which has all types of Categories like NSArray, NSDictionary, NSData, NSManagedObjectContext, NSManagedContext, NSURL, NSString, SA_Connection etc., which is used across the library. SA_Connection is connection class which I suppose connects between Salesforce and App. And other bunch of loose .h/.m files which creates dynamic core data database and retrieving updating database etc., I though if I can mimic SA_Base.framework I can update Salesforce sdk but it is very difficult to find out what exactly the framework does just seeing method names.